# Change bash background color for alternating outputs

Tags: bash

Is it possible to change the background color of outputs from bash alternatively? The reason is that is becomes difficult to distinguish between outputs when they are large. Is there any other way to demarcate them properly?

Comment: can you give an example where's hard to distinguish? not sure what you're talking about. with a colored prompt I've never had this problem.

Comment: The problem arises when the output is colored as well. For example during make install or compiling etc.

Comment: be pragmatic and put something in the prompt that it makes it easy to recognise it.

Comment: so there is no solution apart from visually hunting for prompts?

Comment: @user19448 You technically can alternate colors, the problem is that it works very poorly with commands that use their own colors, like ls and grep. Instead consider e.g. adding a thick yellow line all across your terminal in your prompt.

Comment: @thatotherguy Oh I see. I understand that I cannot use it practically, but could you give the details on how to do the alternating just for curiosity sake? The thick yellow line thing sounds like a reasonable solution. Could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a thick yellow line across your terminal in your prompt:

```
PS1='\[$(tput setab 3)\]$(printf "%-${COLUMNS}s" "";)\[$(tput sgr0)\]
\$ '
```

For fun, here's a simple and horrifyingly ugly alternating color hack:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='(( N++ ))'
PS1='\[$(tput setab $(((N%2)*4)))\]\$'
```